# C++ using inline function in std::sort

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been learning C++ for a last few months.In C++ in order to pass a comparator in std::sort we can easily define a comparator function and pass it as argument to the sorting method.

```
bool myComp(Edge a, Edge b) { return a.wt > b.wt; }
std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), myComp);
```

But i wonder whether there is some more elegant way to do the same thing so that i don't have to explicitly define another function for just one use. In Javascript i can do the same thing by just passing an anonymous function like this:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a.wt > b.wt; });
```

Is that kind of thing possible in C++ or C++11?

Comment: You are looking for [*lambda functions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: [Lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: Ok. I'm reading the link you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been discussed previously, lambdas do indeed exist in C++11: [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)